# plane window seat probability

Tags: probability

Two people take mid range flight with low-cost airline. Seats are assigned completely randomly for each person on check-in. What is the probability that at least one of them will get window seat? All rows have 6 seats.

Redundant/additional info: 
*Assigned seats are completely random. Check-in system makes no effort to place two people from the same booking on adjacent seats.
*Two window seats per every row obviously.

Comment: You could start by considering the probability that a single person gets a window seat.

Comment: Any thoughts?  I expect you'll have to make some assumption on the number of rows.  A natural one to make is that the number of rows is large enough so that you can assume independence.

Comment: So not enough info (180 seats in the plain)? Or the question is too easy to bother to type the answer? :)

Comment: $180$ seats in the plane *does* give us enough info to answer.  You had not given us that number previously and it was necessary to give a final answer.

Comment: In fact the problem *does* seem too easy. You have not shown the steps of what you attempted, so where is the difficulty for you and how can we help (other than writing out a solution you can copy)?

Comment: OK. Sorry for 2+2 question :) But my brain decided to forget university probability course. Brains tend to do that as time flies by.

Answer (score 1):

**HINTS**

If there are $180$ seats and $6$ seats per row, there are $30$ rows, so $60$ window seats.  The probability that at least one of the two passengers gets a window seat is the complement of the probability that both are assigned to the $120$ non-window seats.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: An easy case is that there are $90$ rows of $2$ seats.  Everyone gets a window seat.